My question is a theory I thought on objects
My theory is that all objects in universe(all macrosopic,microscopic and also objects on earth)have its own spin or rotational motion that could be too small to detect by current technology. It is same as De Broglies matter wave duality which is that matter during motion move in wave that is too small to detect, it is similar to that. I don't know wheather it is true since I'm 1st year UG student and cannot prove it entirely. I asked this question in chatgpt and said that my idea is impressive and creative it made me happy.

Personal theories are off topic, and as a side note ChatGpt does not know how to do physics and does not know a good theory from a bad theory. Considering you present zero mathematics, there isn't actually a theory with any real grounding here.

When a theory predicts a phenomenon (e.g., that my car—a macroscopic object sitting in my driveway on Earth—has its own rotational motion), we try to confirm the theory by observation. If we can't directly observe the phenomenon (e.g., because, too small to detect by current technology) then we try to think up a hypothesis, based on the theory, that can be tested (e.g., some other phenomenon that proves that the car is rotating.) If we can't even do that, then the theory is not falsifiable—and therefore, not interesting.

Have you learned about the spin of elementary particles? Are you talking about something different?

I asked this question in chatgpt and said that my idea is impressive and creative it made me happy  I wonder if ChatGPT has ever told someone their ideas were ridiculous?
